# Android: Attempted to serialize ... Forgot to register a type adapter?"

Tags: android, json, gson

How to convert HashMap to JSON using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
class ClassData {
    public String jsonString;
    public Class classType;
}
HashMap<String, ClassData> map = new HashMap<>();

void convert(){
    new Gson().toJson(map); // throws
}
```

I am getting the next exception

> Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: java.lang.String. Forgot to
>   register a type adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement your own custom serializer for ClassData, and then register it to your Gson Builder.

```
public class ClassDataSerializerExample {
    static class ClassData {
        public String jsonString;
        public Class classType;

        public ClassData(String jsonString, Class classType) {
            this.jsonString = jsonString;
            this.classType = classType;
        }
    }

    static class ClassDataSerializer implements JsonSerializer<ClassData> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(ClassData src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            return new JsonPrimitive(src.jsonString);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(ClassData.class, new ClassDataSerializer());

        HashMap<String, ClassData> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key", new ClassData("key", String.class));

        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        String json = gson.toJson(map);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Output: {"key":"key"}

Read more: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer

Answer (score 12):

My approach works for Gson 2.3.1 with Java 1.7, can't guarantee it will work with Android.

The problem lies within the variable `classType`, since Gson can't process the type `Class` as it is. So we have to create a TypeAdapter for Class.

```
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ClassTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Class<?>> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Class<?> clazz) throws IOException {
        if(clazz == null){
            jsonWriter.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        jsonWriter.value(clazz.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            jsonReader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName(jsonReader.nextString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) {
            throw new IOException(exception);
        }
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

To make it work you'll need a TypeAdapterFactory.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class ClassTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if(!Class.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType())) {
            return null;
        }
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new ClassTypeAdapter();
    }
}
```

And register the TypeAdapterFactory to your Gson Builder.

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ClassTypeAdapterFactory());
```

AFAIK you have to use a TypeAdapterFactory. A directly registered TypeAdapter

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new ClassTypeAdapter());
```

seems to be ignored when an object of type `Class` is encountered.

Gson transforms both the `HashMap` and Java class instances to JSON objects.
Example:

```
{
    "hash_key_1": {
        "jsonString": "json_string_instance_1",
        "classType": "my.class.Name1"
    },
    "hash_key_2": {
        "jsonString": "json_string_instance_2",
        "classType": "my.class.Name2"
    }
}
```

Comment: `registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new ClassTypeAdapter())` is working with gson 2.8.5. Thanks for the solution.