# Unable to cast class data stored in SharedPreferences using Gson

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences

I am having a generalized static function defined in `AppController.java` which implements `Application` class. This static function does a job of storing and retrieving serialized class data to and from shared preferences.

**AppController.java**

```
private static GsonBuilder gsonBuilder;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    gsonBuilder= new GsonBuilder();
}

public static void saveObjectToSharedPreferences(Context mContext,String key, Object value){
    if(mContext!=null){
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences=mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(mSharedPreferences!=null) {
            Gson gson=gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
            String storableValue=gson.toJson(value,value.getClass());
            mSharedPreferences.edit().putString(key,storableValue).apply();
        }
    }
}

public static <T> Object readObjectFromSharedPreferences(Context mContext,String key, Class<T> converter ){
    if(mContext!=null){
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(mSharedPreferences!=null){
            Gson gson=gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
            String retrievedValue=mSharedPreferences.getString(key,null);
            if(retrievedValue!=null){
                return gson.fromJson(retrievedValue,converter.getClass());
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I used to call this static functions as below:

```
AppController.saveObjectToSharedPreferences(getContext(), String.valueOf("UserData"), userDetailsObj);
```

My `UserDetails` class is as below:

```
public class UserDetails implements Serializable{
    @Expose
    private String Name;
    @Expose
    private String UserGroup;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getUserGroup() {
        return UserGroup;
    }

    public void setUserGroup(String userGroup) {
        UserGroup = userGroup;
    }
}
```

`saveObjectToSharedPreferences` was successfully saving the `userdetails` object into `SharedPreferences` in the format `{'Name':'somename','UserGroup':'somegroup'}` but I was getting **Attempted to deserialize java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?**, when I tried to retrieve it using `readObjectFromSharedPreferences` function in `gson.fromJson` line. When I searched for this issue throughout, I got to know that we need to specifically write our own `TypeAdapter` for `class` and with the help of **[this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34045000/2065039)** I implemented the said Adapters and wrote `gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ClassTypeAdapterFactory());` during `onCreate` of `AppController class`.

```
public class ClassTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if(!Class.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType())) {
            return null;
        }
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new ClassTypeAdapter();
    }
}
```

Now I've started getting `Method threw 'com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException' exception.` and under detailed message `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`.

I am totally blank at this point of time. Could someone please guide me in the right path to make this work?

Comment: have you register registerTypeAdapterFactory and registerTypeAdapter

Comment: I should register both @Pravin?

Comment: I think yes !!!

Comment: Ok.. Let me try that then.. :)

Comment: Nope.. No luck @Pravin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `readObjectFromSharedPreferences` you are passing `Class<T> converter` and when you are calling `converter.getClass()` it returns `Class` and not `T`. Just remove the `getClass()` call like this:

```
return gson.fromJson(retrievedValue, converter);
```

Also, a nice way to improve this method is to make it return `T` instead of `Object`. This way you won't have to cast anything:

```
public static <T> T readObjectFromSharedPreferences(...)
```

Comment: Exactly.. That's what I was missing. I did not had further need of TypeAdapters or anything else.. Well instead of `T` I used `GenericClass`. Will that be good too?